# Dealing with an os.path.join path with a space in it using subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I am currently using os.path.join to generate the path to a file which looks like the below:-

```
myFile = 'csvfile.csv'
myPath = r'\\mydomain\12345\Original Format\'
myFullPath = os.path.join(myPath, myFile)
```

This outputs:-

```
\\mydomain\12345\Original Format\csvfile.csv
```

This variable works fine however I then need to call this from a subprocess call later on as I wish to run a Windows CLI .exe and pass my variable, myFullPath, as a parameter to the Windows CLI. Unfortunately whenever I run the subprocess.call() function, it fails as it isn't able to handle the space between 'Original Format' within the directory path.

Any suggestions how I can handle this so that the Subprocess call can handle the space in the path?

My Subprocess Call is below:-

```
command = r"C:/Program Files/myExe.exe -user %s -case %s -tags %s" % (username, path, tags)
subprocess.call(command)
```

Thanks

Comment: @zondo I've edited my original question with the subprocess.call. I'm not using a list.

Comment: You can change it to `subprocess.call(["C:/Program Files/myExe.exe", "-user", username, "-case", path, "-tags", tags])`

Comment: Perfect - thanks @zondo

Comment: Given it starts with `\\\` I assume it is a network resource for windows. right?

Comment: Yes @jalazbe it is a network resource

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to make use of os
If you are using windows you need to "scape" each `\` you need to do

```
import os
remote_dir = os.path.join("\\\\","mydomain", "12345","Original Format")
fullpath = os.path.join(remote_dir, "csvfile.csv")
```

It is better to use the proper operating system join. In case there are spaces or other unexpected characters `os.path.join()`will make sure to return the proper separation.